# Lock free read only List in Python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I've done some basic performance and memory consumption benchmarks and I was wondering if there is any way to make things even faster...

1. I have a giant 70,000 element list with a numpy ndarray, and the file path in a tuple in the said list.
2. My first version passed a sliced up copy of the list to each of the processes in python multiprocess module, but it would explode ram usage to over 20+ Gigabytes
3. The second version I moved it into the global space and access it via index such as foo[i] in a loop in each of my processes which seems to put it into a shared memory area/CoW semantics with the processes thus it does not explode the memory usage (Stays at ~3 Gigabytes)
4. However according to the performance benchmarks/tracing, it seems like the large majority of the application time is now spent in "acquire" mode...

So I was wondering if there is any way i can somehow turn this list into some sort of lockfree/read only so that I can do away with part of the acquire step to help speed up access even more.

**Edit 1:** Here's the top few line output of the profiling of the app

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   65 2450.903   37.706 2450.903   37.706 {built-in method acquire}
39320    0.481    0.000    0.481    0.000 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
  600    0.298    0.000    0.298    0.000 {posix.waitpid}
   48    0.271    0.006    0.271    0.006 {posix.fork}
```

**Edit 2:** Here's a example of the list structure:

```
# Sample code for a rough idea of how the list is constructed
sim = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    path = os.path.join(root, filename)
    image= Image.open(path)
    np_array = np.asarray(image)
    sim.append( (np_array, path) )

# Roughly it would look something like say this below
sim = List( (np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32), "/foobar/com/what.something") )
```

Then henceforth the SIM list is to be read only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module provides exactly what you need:  a shared array with optional locking, namely the [`multiprocessing.Array`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) class.  Pass `lock=False` to the constructor to disable locking.

Edit (taking into account your update):  Things are actually considerably more involved than I initially expected. The data of all elements in your list needs to be created in shared memory.  Whether you put the list itself (i.e. the pointers to the actual data) in shared memory, does not matter too much because this should be a small compared to the data of all files.  To store the file data in shared memory, use

```
shared_data = multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray("c", data)
```

where `data` is the data you read from the file.  To use this as a NumPy array in one of the processes, use

```
numpy.frombuffer(shared_data, dtype="c")
```

which will create a NumPy array view for the shared data.  Similarly, to put the path name into shared memory, use

```
shared_path = multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray("c", path)
```

where path is an ordinary Python string.  In your processes, you can access this as a Python string by using `shared_path.raw`.  Now append `(shared_data, shared_path)` to your list.  The list will get copied to the other processes, but the actual data won't.

I initially meant to use an `multiprocessing.Array` for the actual list.  This would be perfectly possible and would ensure that also the list itself (i.e. the pointers to the data) is in shared memory.  Now I think this is not that important at all, as long as the actual data is shared.

Comment: My problem is I need some way to store a numpy ndarray + filepath.  My understanding of the Array stuff is it only stores 1 element such as say 'c' it can't store "char"

Comment: @Pharaun: Maybe I didn't get the structure of your list correctly.  Could you make this more explicit in your question?  I'm pretty sure the `Array` class can be used for your application.

Comment: @Sven, I've updated the question above with a rough sample of how the list is constructed under edit2 so that should give a idea...

Comment: @Pharaun: OK, I will edit my answer to make it more specific.

Comment: @Sven, Hmm never thought about that approach, it'll take some experiment on my behalf to get it to go and completely understand it, but it looks good :)

Comment: @Sven, I tried that approach but Multiprocessing is failing with a pickling error in regard of copying the List over to each process...  It seems to be choking on the RawArray....  So I tried to get the RawArrays into an Array(blah, blah, lock=False) but I'm not having luck here either.... :-\

Comment: @Pharaun: What I did was to create the list at some globally accessible place first before spawning the processes.  This way it does not need to be pickled.  The second approach -- using the Array -- is a bit involved, too.  You need to create a subclass of `ctypes.Structure` and use this class as element type for the Array.

Comment: @Sven On the list, I created 2 list under "if __name__ == '__main__':" which should be in the global namespace...  Then I passed the two lists to the function that deploys it to the pools...  Got a pickle error that way.  I am going to be attempting the ctype.Structure approach now to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Pharaun: If you try to pass it to a process, it needs to be pickled.  If you just create it before forking, every process already *has* it and it does not need to be passed.

Comment: Ah so I would just access it like I would normally access a local list? IE iterate over it?  I think I did that previously but just without using the RawArray to store the data, and I had pretty high {acquire/lock} usage...  Which makes me think I need to use the ctype.Structure + Array w/ lock=False to get around that?

Comment: @Pharaun: There shouldn't be any locking.  I don't know exactly what the problem was before, but there is no implicit locking between multiple processes.  There *is* implicit locking between multiple threads, namely the GIL, but this does not affect processes.