# How to employ something such as openMP in Cython?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmp, cython

Basically I have a problem that is pretty much embrassing parallel and I think I've hit the limits of how fast I can make it with plain python & multiprocessing so I'm now attempting to take it to a lower level via Cython and hopefully openMP.

So in short I am wondering how I can employ openMP with Cython, or if I'll have to wrap some raw C code and load/bind to it via Cython?

Or can I have Cython compile down to C code then modify the C code to add in the openMP pragmas in then compile to library and load it into Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [cython wiki](http://wiki.cython.org/enhancements/parallel), the developers have thought about a variety of options, but I don't believe they have implemented anything yet.

If your problem is embarrassingly parallel, and you already have a multi-processing solution, why not just get each worker process to call some cython code instead of python code?

Comment: That's what I did previously, and it works, but I was running into large memory consumption by each process copying the data over...  Then I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750141/lock-free-read-only-list-in-python which improved things via having a shared memory lockfree, but its still too slow.  So its time for C I believe.

Comment: In that case you're probably best off writing OpenMP enabled C (or fortran) code.  I have found the instructions at http://crashtestastronomer.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/using-a-multithreaded-fortran-module-in-python-using-f2py/ work quite well for fortran, you can probably do something similar in C , then wrap it conveniently using cython.  I prefer fortran 90 over C because you can write array operations just like you do in python with numpy.

Comment: I've successfully implemented this in C and used cython to link it in.

Comment: @Pharaun can you post snippets as an answer?

Answer (score 12):

This question is from 3 years ago and nowadays Cython has available functions that support the OpenMP backend. See for example [the documentation here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html). One very convenient function is the `prange`. This is one example of how a (rather naive) `dot` function could be implemented using `prange`.

**Don't forget** to compile passing the `"/opemmp"` argument to the C compiler.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
from cython.parallel import prange

ctypedef np.double_t cDOUBLE
DOUBLE = np.float64

def mydot(np.ndarray[cDOUBLE, ndim=2] a, np.ndarray[cDOUBLE, ndim=2] b):

    cdef np.ndarray[cDOUBLE, ndim=2] c
    cdef int i, M, N, K

    c = np.zeros((a.shape[0], b.shape[1]), dtype=DOUBLE)
    M = a.shape[0]
    N = a.shape[1]
    K = b.shape[1]

    for i in prange(M, nogil=True):
        multiply(&a[i,0], &b[0,0], &c[i,0], N, K)

    return c

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef void multiply(double *a, double *b, double *c, int N, int K) nogil:
    cdef int j, k
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(K):
            c[k] += a[j]*b[k+j*K]
```

Comment: +1 for the code example for [@yanlend's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378354/4279). [`gcc` requires `-fopenmp`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html). Note: `numpy.dot()` was faster in my [time measurements](https://gist.github.com/zed/2051661). You could accept [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) as an input.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks, this `dot` versions is naive compared to the LAPACK (or similar) routines behind `numpy.dot`, but is a good example. I don't believe memory views would be faster than this, have you tried that?

Comment: I'm aware it is naive (it is [the first word in `cydot.pyx` description](https://gist.github.com/zed/2051661)). Usually parallel computations are used to improve time performance. It is worth mentioning that it is not the case. About typed memoryviews: they produce simpler (no  GIL for memoryview indexing, slicing), more general (non-numpy types are also accepted) and sometimes faster code (I haven't checked in this case).

Answer (score 3):

If somebody stumbles over this question:

Now, there is direct support for OpenMP in cython via the cython.parallel module, see
http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html

Answer (score 2):

[This youtube talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl9La7wH7QI) by Stefan Behnel, one of the core developers of Cython, will give you an amazing intro. Multithreading of a loop is at the last 30 mins (`prange` section). The code is a zipped set of [ipython notebooks downloadable here](http://course.behnel.de/espy2017/all.zip).

In short, write your optimized unthreaded code, optimize with Cython types, and multithread by replacing `range` and releasing the GIL.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with OpenMP, but you may have luck with trying [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3apython) (python bindings included):

`easy_install pyzmq`

Comment: I've heard good thing about zeromq, should put it on my list of thing to do :)  But my problem is I want to avoid interprocess communication because this adds overhead and it explodes memory usage.  Which is why I'm wanting to move to openMP/pthreads so I can have a shared data array of numpy arrays (read only)