# Selectively copy ndarray rows with prange in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, cython

I have a question about a relatively operation I've written in Cython that I'd like to parallelize, but I haven't found any documentation or questions that seem to point in the right direction.

Simply, I want to copy a subset of one array into another array depending on a condition.

I have a large matrix of points, and for each of them I want to check if it's within a certain distance of a center point, and if so, copy it into my results matrix. `out_points` has been allocated to the same size as the input `extent_points`, so that I know it will fit. All variables are `cdef`'ed as ints and ndarrays as appropriate.

```
for pp in range(extent_points.shape[0]):
    meets_condition = 1
    for ii in range(extent_points.shape[1]): # check if in bounds
        if extent_points[pp,ii] < (epicenter[ii] - radius) or \
           extent_points[pp,ii] > (epicenter[ii] + radius):
            meets_condition = 0; break
    if meets-condition == 1: # if in bounds, then copy to output matrix
        for ii in range(extent_points.shape[1]):
            out_points[out_count,ii] = extent_points[pp,ii]
        out_count += 1
return out_points[:out_count, :]
```

It seems like it should be embarrasingly parallel to check this condition on each of my many points in parallel, but it's unclear to me how to parallelize the copy. Should I just mark a  column on the input if it shouldn't be copied and then iterate over again and copy? Is there more prange() documentation besides the short Cython user guide [page](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html) and the [wiki page](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-prange)?

Comment: [this answer gives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22839233/832621) an example about how to use pointers to distribute a region of the array for each process, it may help you in your case...